# OpenCL clBuildProgram, stddef.h/xmmintrin.h not found (cygwin)

Tags: c, cygwin, opencl

I am writing a small program with OpenCL, and invoking:

```
err = clBuildProgram(program, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
printf("%d\n", err);
```

prints **-11**, or **CL_BUILD_PROGRAM_FAILURE**.

I've added this code to debug the error:

```
if (err != CL_SUCCESS) {
    char *buff_erro;
    cl_int errcode;
    size_t build_log_len;
    errcode = clGetProgramBuildInfo(program, device_id, CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG, 0, NULL, &build_log_len);
    if (errcode) {
      printf("clGetProgramBuildInfo failed at line %d\n", __LINE__);
      exit(-1);
    }

    buff_erro = malloc(build_log_len);
    if (!buff_erro) {
      printf("malloc failed at line %d\n", __LINE__);
      exit(-2);
    }

    errcode = clGetProgramBuildInfo(program, device_id, CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG, build_log_len, buff_erro, NULL);
    if (errcode) {
      printf("clGetProgramBuildInfo failed at line %d\n", __LINE__);
      exit(-3);
    }

    fprintf(stderr,"Build log: \n%s\n", buff_erro); //Be careful with  the fprint
    free(buff_erro);
    fprintf(stderr,"clBuildProgram failed\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
```

which prints:

> Build log:  error: /usr/include/CL/cl_platform.h:359:10: 'stddef.h'
>   file not found error: /usr/include/CL/cl_platform.h:359:10: 'stddef.h'
>   file not found error: /usr/include/CL/cl_platform.h:359:10: 'stddef.h'
>   file not found error: /usr/include/CL/cl_platform.h:359:10: 'stddef.h'
>   file not found error: /usr/include/CL/cl_platform.h:359:10: 'stddef.h'
>   file not found error: /usr/include/CL/cl_platform.h:359:10: 'stddef.h'
>   file not found error: /usr/include/CL/cl_platform.h:359:10: 'stddef.h'
>   file not found error: /usr/include/CL/cl_platform.h:359:10: 'stddef.h'
>   file not found error: /usr/include/CL/cl_platform.h:359:10: 'stddef.h'
>   file not found error: /usr/include/CL/cl_platform.h:359:10: 'stddef.h'
>   file not found error: /usr/include/CL/cl_platform.h:359:10: 'stddef.h'
>   file not found error: /usr/include/CL/cl_platform.h:359:10: 'stddef.h'
>   file not found error: /usr/include/CL/cl_platform.h:359:10: 'stddef.h'
>   file not found error: /usr/include/CL/cl_platform.h:359:10: 'stddef.h'
>   file not found error: /usr/include/CL/cl_platform.h:359:10: 'stddef.h'
>   file not found error: /usr/include/CL/cl_platform.h:359:10: 'stddef.h'
>   file not found error: /usr/include/CL/cl_platform.h:359:10: 'stddef.h'
>   file not found error: /usr/include/CL/cl_platform.h:359:10: 'stddef.h'
>   file not found error: /usr/include/CL/cl_platform.h:359:10: 'stddef.h'
>   file not found error: /usr/include/CL/cl_platform.h:359:10: 'stddef.h'
>   file not found error: /usr/include/CL/cl_platform.h:359:10: 'stddef.h'
>   file not found error: /usr/include/CL/cl_platform.h:359:10: 'stddef.h'
>   file not found error: /usr/include/CL/cl_platform.h:359:10: 'stddef.h'
>   file not found error: /usr/include/CL/cl_platform.h:359:10: 'stddef.h'
>   file not found error: /usr/include/CL/cl_platform.h:359:10: 'stddef.h'
>   file not found error: /usr/include/CL/cl_platform.h:359:10: 'stddef.h'
>   file not found error: /usr/include/CL/cl_platform.h:405:18:
>   'xmmintrin.h' file not found error:
>   /usr/include/CL/cl_platform.h:405:18: 'xmmintrin.h' file not found
>
> clBuildProgram failed

I am using Windows 10 / Cygwin, with gcc-core, opencl and opencl-devel installed. I have **stddef.h** and **xmmintrin.h** in **/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/include**. I tried to `cp` them in **/usr/include**, without luck.

If I add:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <xmmintrin.h>
```

to my program, it compiles alright.

Am I missing something here? I should add that I am not an experienced user of Cygwin.

Comment: Any reason to use a compiler still in test mode ? 6.3.0 was not yet released as current gcc compiler

Comment: I was wondering if it was because I didn't have the last version of gcc, therefore tried to update. I tried with 5.4.0 first, and the same errors occured. Thanks for the info, I'll downgrade to 5.4.0! (but to be clear, I still got the errors). + edited my post

Comment: Am I reading this right? You can't #include stddef.h nor xmmintrin.h in an OpenCL kernel.

Comment: I didn't. I included <CL/cl.h> which includes those. And when I said I tried to include them in my program, I was talking about my main, not my OpenCL kernel